# Pass a json list to array in javascript error

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to pass a list in from json to a javascript. I get this error:

**04-03 08:35:49.867: E/NONE(2861): exception. TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined**

The list is as follows:

`{"data":"{\"files\":[{\"name\":\"doc1.pdf\",\"title\":\"networking\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc1.pdf\"},{\"name\":\"doc2.pdf\",\"title\":\"Armoogum\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc2.pdf\"}]}","isSuccessful":true}`

The code is here:

```
var arrayResults = res.responseJSON.data;
alert(arrayResults.length);
var full_list="";
for(var i=0;i<arrayResults.length;i++){ 
  full_list =  full_list + arrayResults[i].data.files.name + "<br />" +  arrayResults[i].data.files.title + '<br />' +  arrayResults[i].data.files.path + '<br />';
  $("#viewlist").html(full_list);  
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code to work with? Are you making an AJAX request with plain JavaScript or with jQuery AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```js
var result = {"data":"{\"files\":[{\"name\":\"doc1.pdf\",\"title\":\"networking\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc1.pdf\"},{\"name\":\"doc2.pdf\",\"title\":\"Armoogum\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc2.pdf\"}]}","isSuccessful":true};

var files = JSON.parse(result.data).files;
var str = '';

for(var file, i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  file = files[i];
  
  str += file.name + '<br>';
}

document.write(str);
```